# Should there be a version issue between SQL Server 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, database-connection

I installed Visual Studio 2010 on my home computer so I could do a little work from home.  After having some issues with SQL Server Express, which got installed by VS2010, I got a copy of SQL Server 2008 R2 from my company.  Let me openly admit I know jack about DBA in SQL Server.

At first it sort of worked, but seemed like I needed to rename the database name every time I opened it.  Now VS2010 won't even open the connection  at all.  I keep getting an error stating one is version 661 and the other is 655 and they're not compatible.  To make matters worse, I can't even attach the database in SQL Server 2008 R2 anymore.

Any ideas on how to rectify this?  Please oversimplify and assume I'm an idiot, because in this case I am.

Answer (score 0):

OK, well apparently VS2010 installs SQL Server 2008 Express on your computer, with which it will happily communicate.  Since I then installed SQL Server 2008 R2 after that, 2008 R2 is considered an upgrade and SQL databases are not backwards compatible.

In order to fix this, I installed [SQL Server Express 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30438) (specifically the SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe file as that one comes with additional tools) and after a reboot I was able to successfully add the database to my VS project.

**NOTE:** I did not remove SQL Server 2008 R2, I merely upgraded SQL Server 2008 **Express*.

As an aside, before doing this I could never have VS and SQL Server 2008 R2 open simultaneously.  After this upgrade, I can have them both open at the same time which is how it should work.